# Differences Between Scoped, Transient, And Singleton Service(.net c#)

Tags: c#, .net

what is really a service and how to use them(.Net)

I try a scope service but i can't understand correctly what does service means

Answer (score 0):

Depencey injection or IOC is a design pattern that will allow register dependant classes like services easily. I would suggest you read more about https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-7.0

In .net core there are three methods:

Scoped will call the service per request,

Singlton will call the service per application

Transient will call the service per request once it is requested .